# VUE & JS: Disable all keyboard events except copy-paste (CTRL + C) on contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how do I disable all keyboard events on a `contenteditable` element while allowing the content to be copy-pasted?

User should still see the mouse cursor

tried this doesn't work:

```js
const inputEvt = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (e.keyCode === 91 && e.keyCode === 67) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    };
```

reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-wiles-bx8oe

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552), where the answer is No.

Comment: There's no `contenteditable` element (unless you're using a custom element named `contenteditable`). You're probably referring to an element that has the `contenteditable` attribute/property.

Answer (score 1):

You could update `inputEvt` to check for `ctrlKey` or `metaKey` (on macOS, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> are copy and paste respectively) along with `C` or `V`. Also move the `e.preventDefault()` to the `else` clause, or else the copy/paste action would be prevented:

```js
const inputEvt = (e) => {
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode === 91 || e.keyCode === 67)) {
    return true;
  }

  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
};
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/preventing-keyboard-interaction-5ur8t?file=/src/App.vue:530-757)

Alternatively, you could just use set [`readonly=true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly) on the `input` element to avoid having to hook the keys:

```html
<input readonly>
```